# Future value formula displays output of insanely huge number

Tags: c++

I am obviously new :(  It is my formula, but this has been the only way I can even get it to run at all. It just displays an insanely big number and I don't understand how to write it. Please have mercy on my newbie soul...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    float F, P, i;
    int t;

    cout << "Enter how much money is currently in the account: ";
    cin >> P;
    while (P < 1)   // Amount can not be less that $1
    {
        cout << "Value must be at least $1, enter another amount: ";
        cin >> P;                   
    }

    cout << "Enter the monthly interest rate: ";
    cin >> i;

    cout << "Enter how many months this money will be in the account: ";
    cin >> t;


    F = P * pow( 1 + i,(t * 12));

    cout << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << "Original:" << setfill(' ') << setw(20) << "$" << P << endl;
    cout << "Monthly Interest:" << setfill(' ') << setw(12) << "$" << i << endl;
    cout << "Future amount:" << setfill(' ') << setw(15) << "$" << F;


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: give us a sample input and output, would you;-)?

Comment: Interest formula looks wrong. I'd check that against a reference before going any further.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned in the comments, the issue is located in your interest formula. Please change it to the following:

```cpp
    F = P * pow( 1 + i/(P * 12),(t * 12));
```

As you insert the monthly interest rate `i` in $, hence as a absolute value, you need to calculate the relative one `i / P`. Also the compounding frequency is missing, which shall be every month in your question. Therefore the 12 has to be added in the denominator.

Please have a look to Wikipedia for further [information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest), especially in section Calculation.

Hope it helps.